# How to load other web page in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to load some fixed part from other website to my web application.
How to accomplish this?
Thanks.

Comment: Peraps you can give some more detailed information, please ? this is too ambiguous/unspecific... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it in a few ways:

1. On the client side, load the content into an `<iframe>`
2. <strike>On the client side, load the content using `ajax` and write it into the page.</strike>
3. On the server side, load the page using `WebClient` `DownloadString` and write it into your page.

**Update**

After you get your string, you might parse it and grab the stuff you want using the [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) . (Also available on Nuget)

Comment: My mistake, I'll take it off.

Comment: Thanks, it works.
But I want only selected part(coordinates specified) to load

Comment: See my update. The "only" way to parse HTML data on the server is using the Html Agility Pack.

Comment: @Jay If the part you want has some fixed formatting e.g. it always appear between "START HERE" and "END HERE" you can use simple string methods like `IndexOf` to find the part you need. Post sample data and explain what part you need and we'll try to see.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `WebRequest` for this task:

```
string url = "http://somesite.com/somepage.php";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
    //parse contents as you wish.......
    reader.Close();
}
response.Close();
```

Comment: Easier though is the webclient : WebClient client = new WebClient(); string html = WebClient.DownloadString("http://www.myurl.com");

Comment: @Gidon thanks, I'm not yet familiar enough with the WebClient but from quick look it looks like more simple way that is using the given code "behind the scenes". :)

Comment: It's indeed a wrapper, which takes most of the ugly works out of your hands. Has some neat methods in there.

Comment: @Gid yup saw it. Reminds me of having the `File.WriteAllText()` method wrapping the ugly Stream stuff. :)

Comment: I think WebClient DownloadString is more easier and proper